# calculate rolling mean with lookback period efficiently in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
                     cumm_vol  cumm_vol_LB
datetime                                  
2018-01-01 09:15:00     93228            0
2018-01-01 09:16:00    124353            0
2018-01-01 09:17:00    184578            0
2018-01-01 09:18:00    237003            0
2018-01-01 09:19:00    264303            0
2018-01-01 09:20:00    310503            0
2018-01-02 09:15:00    170928            0
2018-01-02 09:16:00    261528            0
2018-01-02 09:17:00    358653            0
2018-01-02 09:18:00    438678            0
2018-01-02 09:19:00    559503            0
2018-01-02 09:20:00    626178            0
2018-01-03 09:15:00    175953            0
2018-01-03 09:16:00    294078            0
2018-01-03 09:17:00    395853            0
2018-01-03 09:18:00    447078            0
2018-01-03 09:19:00    486903            0
2018-01-03 09:20:00    523578            0
2018-01-04 09:15:00     82727            0
2018-01-04 09:16:00    129077            0
2018-01-04 09:17:00    162752            0
2018-01-04 09:18:00    194852            0
2018-01-04 09:19:00    239027            0
2018-01-04 09:20:00    291677            0
```

I have to calculate the mean of `cumm_vol` at each 1 min interval for last x days window and add it to the current `cumm_vol_LB` column and this rolls forward for each day for e.g. with x=2 the mean of `cumm_vol` at 09:15:00 for dates 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-02 will be zero and for 2018-01-03 will be (93228+170928)/2 = 132078
So the expected output will be a sort of rolling mean:

```
                     cumm_vol  cumm_vol_LB
datetime                                  
2018-01-01 09:15:00     93228            0
2018-01-01 09:16:00    124353            0
2018-01-01 09:17:00    184578            0
2018-01-01 09:18:00    237003            0
2018-01-01 09:19:00    264303            0
2018-01-01 09:20:00    310503            0
2018-01-02 09:15:00    170928            0
2018-01-02 09:16:00    261528            0
2018-01-02 09:17:00    358653            0
2018-01-02 09:18:00    438678            0
2018-01-02 09:19:00    559503            0
2018-01-02 09:20:00    626178            0
2018-01-03 09:15:00    175953            132078
2018-01-03 09:16:00    294078            192940.5
2018-01-03 09:17:00    395853            271615.5
2018-01-03 09:18:00    447078            337840.5
2018-01-03 09:19:00    486903            523203
2018-01-03 09:20:00    523578            468340.5
..........
```

The way I am trying to do currently is to filter out data for dates of lookback period=2 and simultaneously `groupby` transform based on time and build a new dataframe.

```
for dateix,date in enumerate(dates):
        nifty_datewise = nifty_data.groupby('date').get_group(date)
        nifty_datatemp = groupbytime(nifty_data, nifty_datewise, dates, dateix)
        nifty_main = nifty_main.append(nifty_datatemp)
def groupbytime(nifty_datafrm, nifty_datewise, dates, dateix):
    if dateix-2>=0:
        nifty_data = nifty_datafrm.loc[dates[dateix-2]: dates[dateix]]
        datesNew = nifty_data["date"].dt.date.unique()
        lookback_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for datei,date in enumerate(datesNew):
            nifty_df = nifty_data.groupby('date').get_group(date)
            lookback_df = lookback_df.append(nifty_df)
        nifty_datewise["cumm_vol_LB"] = lookback_df.groupby('time')['cumm_vol'].transform('mean')
        return nifty_datewise
    else:
        return nifty_datewise
```

This doesn't seem to be the optimal solution. Looking for best practice for achieving this, may be pandas has something inbuilt for such usecase, `.rolling` didn't help as it works row by row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When refactoring my first answer, I figured out that pandas has a very good handling of time series data. You can read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) about it. Also, grouping the data with `groupby` seems pretty efficient and does not create superfluous copies of data, as I thought originally.

Answer A scales much better (linearly) with the dataset size than answer B. I could compute a 20k case in about 100ms (measured with `%timeit` in `ipython`). Find below an excerpt of the data I was testing with.

---

### Answer A:

This approach groups the data by minutes and subsequently applies a moving average filter over the groups. Read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions) about window functions in pandas. A list of available offset aliases to specify time deltas is given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

```
def assign_rolling_average(x, dt):
    x.cumm_vol_LB = x.cumm_vol.rolling(window=dt).mean()
    return x

dt='3D' # width of rolling average window: 3 days
# Group data by the time.
g = df.groupby(lambda x: x.time())   
# Apply the moving average filter on all groups. 
df = g.apply(assign_rolling_average, dt=dt)
```

---

### Answer B (much slower):

This was my original answer. It manually identifies the rows to operate upon. It involves multiple operations with full-length logical indices and likely suffers from [data locality problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). It scales quadratically in runtime with the problem size.

```
from datetime import timedelta

# Time delta: fix here the width of the time window
dt = timedelta(days=3)

# Iterate over the rows
for idx in df.index:
    date, time = idx.date(), idx.time()
    mask = ((df.index.time == time)         # Same time of the day
            & (df.index.date <= date)       # Not later than today 
            & (df.index.date >= (date-dt))) # Not older than (today - dt)
    df.loc[idx, 'cumm_vol_LB'] = df.loc[mask, 'cumm_vol'].mean()
```

---

This is the dataframe I tested with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["2018-01-01 09:15:00",  93228, 0],
                   ["2018-01-01 09:16:00", 124353, 0],
                   ["2018-01-01 09:17:00", 184578, 0],
                   ["2018-01-01 09:18:00", 237003, 0],
                   ["2018-01-01 09:19:00", 264303, 0],
                   ["2018-01-01 09:20:00", 310503, 0],
                   ["2018-01-02 09:15:00", 170928, 0],
                   ["2018-01-02 09:16:00", 261528, 0],
                   ["2018-01-02 09:17:00", 358653, 0],
                   ["2018-01-02 09:18:00", 438678, 0],
                   ["2018-01-02 09:19:00", 559503, 0],
                   ["2018-01-02 09:20:00", 626178, 0],
                   ["2018-01-03 09:15:00", 175953, 0],
                   ["2018-01-03 09:16:00", 294078, 0],
                   ["2018-01-03 09:17:00", 395853, 0],
                   ["2018-01-03 09:18:00", 447078, 0],
                   ["2018-01-03 09:19:00", 486903, 0],
                   ["2018-01-03 09:20:00", 523578, 0],
                   ["2018-01-04 09:15:00",  82727, 0],
                   ["2018-01-04 09:16:00", 129077, 0],
                   ["2018-01-04 09:17:00", 162752, 0],
                   ["2018-01-04 09:18:00", 194852, 0],
                   ["2018-01-04 09:19:00", 239027, 0],
                   ["2018-01-04 09:20:00", 291677, 0]],
                  columns = ['datetime', 'cumm_vol', 'cumm_vol_LB']
                  )
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: Here the window is not factored in. So for a large dataset cum_average will take average of full dataset at each minute interval rather than for last X days window which will not be expected result.Also the window keeps moving forward.

Comment: @AdityaMertia Ah, I misread your problem description. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: @ normanius Thanks your code mostly works. I have however used your code to modify it slightly. But its certainly optimized version of what i was trying. I also want to see if `.resample` can be used in this usecase to come up with similar results.

Comment: Don't know `resample` that well. To me it looks that it can be used only to modify the resolution on the timeline (e.g. from mins to hours), but not to sample timestamps on the timeline with a specific pattern (e.g. "every day, same time of day").

Comment: @ normanius BTW this code works for a small file of lets say 20-30 lines but very slow for a slightly bigger file of say 5000-10000 lines and around 35-40 min for a 20-30k data file. I think this is what I was referring to about my code not being optimized.

Comment: @AdityaMertia Well, you were right, an approach using `groupby` and `rolling` definitely works better than mine. I refactored my answer once more.

Comment: @ normanius But the output of the program doesn't match the output expected. If dt=3D, then it should take means of values at each minute over last 3 days and populate the mean value of each minute into the current days(i.e. 4th day) each minute respectively. I have taken your code from Answer A and the output doesn't match the OD.

Comment: @AdityaMertia For both answers A and B I get the same expected output. See [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P9Lks6cX) to see the output I get. I tested with pandas 0.22 on python3.6.

Comment: (sorry for the multiple posts, I had some c&p issues)

Comment: @ normanius I am having issue with a slightly larger file. Rolling doesn't seem to work as expected. I have uploaded my version of code (@https://pastebin.com/CErzQCqU) and input data(@https://pastebin.com/7J3keRE1) Basically i use window='10D' which is expected to skip first 10 dates and populate cumm_vol_LB from 11th onwards. But the output is unexpected with only 1st date skipped and not 10. The input data has business days instead of calender days. I also use min_periods=10 such that first 10 days calc are skipped.

Comment: @AdityaMertia Alright, the problem was that I grouped by *minute* instead of *time of day*. So, for example 10:59:00, 11:59:00, 12:59:00 etc. fell into the same group, which is not what you want. The bug is fixed now.

Comment: Next bug you fix yourself, okay? :)